# Saving and loading spinner value using sharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, android-spinner, android-sharedpreferences

I tried to save and load the selected item in the `spinner` using `sharedPreferences`. Even though the code shows no errors, it's not working. Somebody help.

```
country=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.countries_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

public void saveFile(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(FileName,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPref.edit();
        int userChoice = country.getSelectedItemPosition();
        editor.putInt("userChoiceSpinner",userChoice);
}

public void readFile(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(FileName,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int spinnerValue = sharedPref.getInt("userChoiceSpinner",0);
        country.setSelection(spinnerValue);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to use [**`editor.apply();`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor#apply()) to save value in `SharedPreferences`

> [**`editor.apply();`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor#apply())

- Commit your preferences changes back from this Editor to the `SharedPreferences` object it is editing. This atomically performs the requested modifications, replacing whatever is currently in the `SharedPreferences`.

Try this

```
    public void saveFile(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(FileName,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPref.edit();
        int userChoice = country.getSelectedItemPosition();
        editor.putInt("userChoiceSpinner",userChoice);
        editor.apply();
    }
```

Comment: The missing piece was indeed the submission of the edit: `apply()`.

Comment: @BIBINJOHNY `not working` means did you get any error

Comment: I haven't got any errors. But it is not getting saved. I have added some editTexts and they are getting saved properly. I am not able to find out the reason.

Comment: @BIBINJOHNY you `country` is empty check you are not setting adapter in it change it to `spinner`

Comment: @BIBINJOHNY share crash log with question

Comment: I have created a separate activity for this. When I try start the activity, the app gets closed. This is what happens.

Answer (score 0):

You set country and spinner both same id show may one spinner not set data

```
country=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
```